# split input into lines instead of limiting lines

Tags: python, irc, command-line-interface

I'm making a configuration file generator and need to parse text into multiple lines without limiting the lines they want to use, so they have as many as they want. The exact example of this would be the /admin command on IRC, like the following would be what is put in and printed out:

```
    What are your admin {} lines? (delimited with some character.. lets say |)
    prompt> Nickname: Iota | Real Name: Fat Chance | Email: iota{at}electrocode.net
    .
    .
    .
    (after everything else is done its printed out/echoed or added to a file(what I plan on doing)
    admin {
        "Nickname: Iota";
        "Real Name: Fat Chance";
        "Email: iota{at}electrocode.net";
    };

    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How would one go about making that happen xD I'm usually good at this, but I'm stumped on how to make it happen, I know I'd have to use raw_input or input, but don't know how to get it to parse the text the way I want it

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and edit your question, because now it is totally unclear what are you expecting from us. And please show some code you have written so far, with sample input and output.

Comment: I don't have any code for that block since I don't know how to make it print out the way I want it, I've been told str.split(), but that doesn't do what I need it to, like from a list of input that was delimited by the | and parsed into a list, or just from making a | into a newline, I am genuinely stumped and wanted help, I can get multiple lines, but I'd need to limit it at some point unless i make some automation and ask for how many lines they want, but I want it to be just one question asked for it, as shown, and then they put their text in, delimited by the character,

Comment: then parsed and printed out in that fashion of admin { ... }; or written/appended to a file

Comment: See my comment on your answer ._. the page didn't update and I get no other indication that someone has written anything..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
user_input = raw_input("prompt>")
print 'admin {'
for line in user_input.split('|'):
    print '"{0}";'.format(line.strip())
print '}'
```

Comment: hmm that might be it, let me go test, and sorry about the 'what' my page didn't update like it did for @m-wasowski

Comment: Seems to be it, thank you very much :> Credits for the help going in as well

Comment: Just for arguments sake, I was also told
    while True:
        line = raw_input("> ")
        if not line:
            break
        admin_block.append(line)
for catching lines, just in the way that I don't have to parse |
this way I just enter a newline when I want to stop